# boto-emr job error: python broken pipeline error and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, emr

I've prepared a streaming `boto` jobflow on AWS/EMR that runs perfectly well using the familiar test pipe:

```
 sed -n '0~10000p'  Big.csv | ./map.py | sort -t$'\t' -k1 | ./reduce.py
```

The boto emr job run also works well as I increase the size of the input data, until some threshold where jobs fail with a python broken pipe error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201504151813_0001/attempt_201504151813_0001_r_000002_0/work/./reduce.py", line 18, in <module>
json.dump( { "cid":cur_key , "promo_hx":kc } , sys.stdout ) 
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 181, in dump
fp.write(chunk)
 IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

and the following java error:

```
  org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed (Thread-38): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I'm *assuming* the memory error occurs first, leading to the broken pipeline.

Mapping tasks all complete for any input data size; the error occurs at the reducer stage. My reducer is the usual streaming reducer (I am using AMI 3.2.3 with the `jason` package built into Python 2.6.9):

```
 for line in sys.stdin:
      line                = line.strip()
      key  , value        = line.split('\t')
      ...
      print json.dumps( { "cid":cur_key , "promo_hx":kc } , sort_keys=True , separators=(',',': ') )
```

Any idea what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to increase the reducer memory size. This can be done by instance type (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration_H2.html for defaults by instance type) or by adjusting the `mapreduce.reduce.*` properties either at the job level or cluster level (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#PredefinedbootstrapActions_ConfigureHadoop).

Comment: This sounds like the right solution path. I'm looking into how to change `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` from within `boto`. Otherwise the solution is to select the next larger EC2 instance type. Right now I'm using m1.medium, and this should really get the job done. I'll follow-up.

Comment: Accessing hadoop parameters within boto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071436/setting-hadoop-parameters-with-boto

Comment: The link below also helped: hadoop parameters are passed via bootstrap, and it's important to use the right `BootstrapAction` ( a function from `boto.emr.boostrap_action`): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boto-users/cEUJvertqWY

Comment: List of hadoop tasks parameters (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html) and AWS's own task config parms (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration_H2.html)